# Wireguard roaming client IP over multiple server

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, wireguard

I have 2 servers (S1 & S2) on 2 different ISP.
They are connected through a Wireguard tunnel (10.0.100.0/24).

I have different mobile devices that connect on S1 or S2.

Today, when a mobile device connects to S1, it is on 10.0.1.0/24 network and when it is connected to S2, it is on 10.0.2.0/24.

With very basic routing, any mobile device can reach both servers.

I need to implement an architecture that allows mobile devices to keep the same IP no matter if they are connected to S1 or S2, that they can reach both servers and reach each other mobile devices.

I looked for VxLAN but wireguard forwards L3, not L2. I looked to dynamic routing protocols too but I can't know when a client is connected or not...

Does anyone have an idea to solve my need?

P.S. : I can install any software on servers but it must be transparent to mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Periodically monitor your WireGuard interfaces using `wg show $IF latest-handshakes`. A single monitoring host needs to periodically collect the handshake timestamps from both servers to determine which server is the "active" server for each peer, then it needs to add kernel routes for that peer's AllowedIPs on that server and remove them on the other server.

```
ssh $active_host "ip route add 2a06:e881:108:28::8/128 dev wg0"
ssh $inactive_host "ip route del 2a06:e881:108:28::8/128 dev wg0"
```

(Normally wg-quick adds such routes statically for all peers – if you are indeed using wg-quick to set up WireGuard, you would need to disable this using Table=off and let the monitoring system take care of it.)

Configure your dynamic routing software (Bird2 or FRR or other) to import those static routes from kernel and to redistribute them to the other server as well as your main gateway. (OSPF would be a good way to do it, although beware that Bird2 had bugs<sup>1</sup> related to 'device' routes that seem to only have been fixed in the very latest version; you might want to try FRR instead.)

Note that for this to work, the two servers need to be "adjacent", i.e. if they don't have a direct connection then you must set up a dedicated GRE or WireGuard tunnel between them, to run the routing protocol.

The result is that your network should have an internal routing table full of /32's and /128's for each client device, pointing to one server or the other.

---

<sup>1</sup> To be fair, I am not entirely sure whether they were indeed Bird2 bugs, or whether they came from the another OSPF implementation that was also running on my network, though they did eventually go away.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this solution but i am afraid that it isn't enough robust and the route switching enough quick. It isn't relevant if I need 10 to 30 second to get a vpn connection.

Comment: And it is more an hack than a networking solution... But if it is the only solution...

Comment: If you want to make it quick enough, you could change it to react to "new handshake" notifications from the kernel, received via Netlink. But unfortunately I don't think WireGuard provides those yet. (It's similar to how routing daemons are able react to things like "new route" or "interface down" notifications, without having to re-check the entire routing table every minute.)

Comment: (There might be a workaround – it might be possible to make the servers react to WireGuard packets from new addresses using iptables NFLOG or NFQUEUE to immediately trigger a "latest-handshakes" check.)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way to implement a "real networking solution" with WireGuard as it is currently – not without running some dynamic-routing software on the individual endpoints, at least. If I remember correctly, services such as Tailscale and CF WARP use customized WireGuard implementations to make this work.

Comment: Okey thank you for thoses informations ! I will check if I can receive a notification. If i can't, I will script your first solution.

Comment: Create an iptables rule that sends incoming wireguard packets via NFLOG or NFQUEUE, then you'll be able to react to them from userspace. (Probably better performance than libpcap.) Or as yet another alternative, enable wireguard module dynamic debugging, then it will announce each handshake in dmesg.